# Sum over the rows of a cell matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a variable classi which is composed out of cells (**269x500**), it can be found here http://ojtwist.be/data.mat . I'm trying to sum the rows of this matrix so that i get a vector of **269x1**. I tried converting the variable to a matrix with cell2mat but this doesn't work. Or matlab sees the sign (-) as a seperate cell. Therefore i can't use `sum(classi(:),2)`. My question is now, how can I do this efficiently ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do it:

```
load data.mat

a = sum( cellfun(@str2double, classi), 2);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `a = cellfun(@(x) str2num(x), classi);` to convert the cellstr to num?